# How to load image data in HTML from a C# Server

Tags: c#, html

I have a simple C# Server and a web page. I am having problem while loading images. If I run
the HTML Page directly from a web browser then the image loads but when my Server send's it then I recieve a request : GET /Image.jpg /1.0 , something like that. I want to know how to respond to this request.

My Server Code is:

```
// .... TcpListener Started ....
// .... Listener accepts request ...
    while (Data != null)                                    //Sending Web Page (HTML)
                    {
                        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Data);
                        StreamWriter.Flush();
                        Console.Write(Data);                   
                        Data = File.ReadLine();
                    }

Request = StreamReader.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine(Request);

//Server requested for Image   "GET /Image.jpg /1.0"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is your friend. Something like this should work:

```
byte[] image = GetMyImage();

StreamWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
StreamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
StreamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + image.Length);
StreamWriter.WriteLine("");
StreamWriter.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
```

Comment: I tried this method and many many more but still I cannot see the image on the browser. This is confirm that the < byte[] image > is going to the browser because instead of the picture, bytes are showed on the browser. Any Solution ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure. Content-type should have done the trick. maybe check some other examples how they did it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17071/Sample-HTTP-Server-Skeleton-in-C or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of effort finally, this worked for me :

```
Stream Stream = ListenerClient.GetStream();
                byte[] bt = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/Private/Desktop/a.wmv");

                Stream.Write(bt, 0, bt.Length);
```